# How to achieve building an Android app using Apache Cordova with fully immersive mode (no Android bars anywhere - battery, time, ..)?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I code a small game based on JS framework Phaser 3. To build it for an Android I use Apache Cordova. Currently I'm trying to hide all Android bars using `cordova-plugin-fullscreen`. It helps a bit by hiding a bottom bar but top bar with battery state and clock still remains (as shown on image lower). So my question is: How to get rid of that top bar too?

This is code I call at start of the app which successfully hides bottom bar (but not the top one):

```
AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode(successFunction, errorFunction);
```

[image: Screenshot of app showing the top bar with clock, battery, wifi icon, ...]